# controlling subgraphs independently

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code  (most important parts)

```
import csv
import sys
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
from pprint import pprint as pp

...

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

l, = plt.plot(x,y1, label="kw")
l, = plt.plot(x,y2, label="pred")

plt.xlabel('date/time')
plt.ylabel('kw_energy')
plt.title("Gym")
plt.legend()

formatter = DateFormatter('%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
plt.gcf().axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

locs, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.setp(labels, rotation=45)

plt.grid()

x_min_index = 0
x_max_index = 96

x_min = x[x_min_index]
x_max = x[x_max_index]

x_dt = x_max - x_min

y_min = plt.axis()[2]
y_max = plt.axis()[3]

plt.axis([x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max])

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axpos = plt.axes([0.2, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)

slider_max = len(x) - x_max_index - 1

spos = Slider(axpos, 'Pos', matplotlib.dates.date2num(x_min), matplotlib.dates.date2num(x[slider_max]))
spos.valtext.set_visible(False)

def update(val):
    pos = spos.val
    xmin_time = matplotlib.dates.num2date(pos)
    xmax_time = matplotlib.dates.num2date(pos) + x_dt
    # DEBUG:
    print "x_min: %s, x_max: %s" % (xmin_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"), xmax_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))
    print pos
    print spos.valtext
    print "##################"

    xmin_time = pos
    ax.axis([xmin_time, xmax_time, y_min, y_max])

spos.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Produces this plot
[image]

Now I want to add another subplot and being able to control both independently. I have this:

```
plt.close('all')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

line0 = ax[0].plot(x,y1, lw=2, label='kw_energy_consumption')
line1 = ax[1].plot(x,y2, lw=2, label='prediction')
```

Now I want to set the name for whole figure, and also for particular sub graphs. I've tried this bud gives an error:

```
line0.set_title("Title for second plot")
```

Then I've read about switching between plots and figures but it also gives errors

```
plt.subplots(211)
```

or

```
plt.subplots(1)
```

How can I control both sub graphs independently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a title to `ax[0]` by simply saying

```
ax[0].set_title('blah')
```

You cannot set title to a patch (in your case the line objects).

Interestingly, there's often a method for an `ax` object corresponding to one for `matplotlib.pyplot`.

Comment: This is true for setting the title but I am searching for something more general. E.g. how to rotate x labels. I've specified the details, please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31372953/plt-setp-alternative-for-subplots-or-how-to-set-text-rotation-on-x-axis-for-subp

Comment: you can use something like `ax[0].set_xticklabels(..., rotation=70)`

Comment: I've tried add `line1_labels = axarr[1].get_xticklabels()` and `axarr[0].set_xticklabels(line1_labels, rotation=45)` but instead of values I get weird numbers (which had rotation of 45 degrees)

Comment: Something like `Text(2,0,u'Text(2,0,u"Text(0.4,u\'0.4\')")')`. I've added those lines just before plt.show()